# Flutter remove space between widget in column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Hi I have `modalRoute` with column inside
but between widget it has vertical space like divider, my `modalRoute` `black.Withtransparent` so that transparent `color` make a divider row between widget, how to remove that space ?

```
return SlideTransition(
position: panelDetailsPosition,
child: GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
  },
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
      GestureDetector(
        onVerticalDragUpdate: _handleDragUpdate,
        onVerticalDragEnd: _handleDragEnd,
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
            height: 47.0,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(25.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(25.0)),
                  color: Colors.white),
              child: Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(180.0, 20.0, 180.0, 20.0),
                child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey[300],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            const Radius.circular(8.0)))),
              ),
            )),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: PageView(
          controller: _pageViewController,
          // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: <Widget>[
            pageViewItem(),
            pageViewDeskripsi(),
            pageViewItemPilihan()
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
                color: CompanyColors.primary,
                child: Center(
                  child: InkWell(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Add to Cart",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      gotToPilihan();
                    },
                  ),
                )),
          )
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

[image]

here is when i change the container color to check what part of it

-container with lightblue color

-container with no color (background is from other page before push ModalRoute)

-container with green

[image]

Comment: change the color of your container to check which is the part that add those lines

Comment: the color come from this, when i change color to red, the lines color changed to line, its transparent color of materialRoute
class MenuItem extends ModalRoute<void> {
  
  @override
  Color get barrierColor => Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7);

Comment: You can update your code also, but do it on the question (update the question with the imagen and code with colors ) , remove your answer below

Comment: so how to make that gap dissappear ? @diegoveloper

Answer (score 1):

That's a known issue of Flutter, more detail on Github: [#14288](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14288). There are some workarounds, but none of them works all the time.